# How to check and uncheck checkbox based on a button click (with text change of button) in Mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have button: Turn Email On and checkbox (which is unchecked) on side of that button.

When I click `Turn email on` button,it should call action method of controller where I have to write SP to update the email table.

Email_ON_OFF_T table have one field: isemailon_off(int type). I inserted value 0 into it.

So, `Turn email on` button's text will become `turn email off` and checkbox becomes checked.

I have tried the following code:

```
    <div class="col-md-8 form-group" style="text-align:right;">

                    <input type="button" value="Turn Email ON" class="btn btn-success" id="btnturnemailonoff" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 form-group">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="Chkemailonoff" />
                </div>
```

Ajax code to call button:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('#btnturnemailonoff').on('click', function () {
                        //var prices = [];
                        //$('#Chkemailonoff').each(function () {

                        //    prices.push($(this).attr("value"));
                        //});
                        var checked = !$(this).data('checked');
                        $("#Chkemailonoff").prop('checked', checked);
                        $(this).val(checked ? 'Turn Email Off' : 'Turn Email on')
                        $(this).data('checked', checked);
                        debugger;
                        var url = '@Url.Action("CheckEmail", "BillingDetails")';
                        $.ajax({
                            url: url,
                            type: "POST",
                            data: { checkemails: checked },
                            dataType: "json",
                           // traditional: true,
                            success: function () {
                                alert("ajax request to server succeed");
                            }
                        });
                    });
                });
```

From Ajax, I am passing data(view) to the Controllers action Method.

```
    [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult CheckEmail(string checkemails)
            {

                //how to call Stored Procedure
                return new JsonResult { };
            }
```

I have written the below SP:

```
    ALTER procedure [dbo].[Sp_Email_on_off]
    @checkemails varchar(10)
    As
    Begin
    if(@checkemails='false')
    Update Email_ON_OFF_T set isEmailON_OFF=1 
    else
    Update Email_ON_OFF_T set isEmailON_OFF=0 

    End
```

The thing where I am stuck is the stored procedure. How to write and execute Sp in Controllers action Method? This is my first task in MVC. How to achieve this using Mvc?

Comment: Do you use DbContext or ADO.net, my friend?

Comment: @Tomato32...entity model...  .edmx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **FromSql** or **ExecuteSqlCommand** to execute stored procedure.

FromSql can only be used to execute raw SQL queries or stored procedures to get the data. You can’t use it for INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE. If you want to execute INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE queries, use the ExecuteSqlCommand. It returns integer value which indicates the count of affected rows.

Here is a sample following your requirement. Hope to help, my friend :))

```
if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(checkemails))
{
    dataContext.Database
           .ExecuteSqlCommand("Sp_Email_on_off @checkemails", checkemails);
}
```

Comment: can you help me with this link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56968888/maintain-the-state-of-checkbox-on-page-load-in-mvc?noredirect=1#comment100474649_56968888