# How to convert Kendo dropdownlist into Kendo multiselect

Tags: c#, ajax, model-view-controller, kendo-ui

I am converting Kendo dropdownlist from the existing code into Kendo multiselect.

Role Code: Currently Dropdownlist (converting to Kendo multiselect).

I am not getting the correct output.

I have the following code:

```
<div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RoleCode, htmlAttributes: new { }) <span style="color: Red">*</span>
                <select id="DDRolecode" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Select attendees...">

        </select>


</div>
...
...
var url = '@Url.Action("GetRoleCode", "FlowGenerator")';
            url = url + '?FlowID=' + flowid + '&RegID=' + RegId;
            $.ajax({


                url: url,
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'POST',

                success: function (result) {

                    debugger;

                    //$("#DDRolecode").kendoDropDownList({
                    //    dataTextField: "Name",
                    //    dataValueField: "ID",
                    //    optionLabel: "Select",
                    //    dataSource: result

                    //});

                    $("#DDRolecode").kendoMultiSelect({
                        dataTextField: "Name",
                        dataValueField: "ID",                       
                        dataSource: result,
                    });

                     var selectedData = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {


                        selectedData.push({
                            text: result[i].Name,
                            value: result[i].ID
                        })

                    }

                    DDRoleCode.dataSource.data(selectedData);
                    //DDRoleCode.setDataSource(selectedData);
                    DDRoleCode.value('');
                    DDRoleCode.enable(true);

                },
                error: function (data) {
                    debugger;
                    var itemRow = "<ul id='listError'><li>" + "Data Not Bind" + "</li></ul>";
                    FUNMessageBox(itemRow, "E", 0, 0, "", "");
                    // alert("error");
                }
            });
```

The below is the controller code where I am getting the role codes:

```
 public JsonResult GetRoleCode(int FlowID,int RegID)
        {
            IEnumerable<GenericValues1> RoleCode = _repository.Context.Database.SqlQuery<GenericValues1>("PROC_GET_ROLECODE @DATA_FLOW_ID={0},@REG_ID={1}", FlowID, RegID).ToList().AsQueryable();

           // ViewBag.Tariffs = RoleCode;
            return Json(RoleCode, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


        }
```

As you can see, I tried using the multiselect functionality in the above code. But it didn't work.

Comment: Which part isn't specifically working? As in is the data source not being bound? Are your selected values not being preset? The code helps to try and track the problem but you haven't said what the specific problem is.

Comment: @DavidShorthose https://ibb.co/Ln6zQ4w Kindly check the link.This is what i am getting.

Comment: But again you aren't saying/showing what the actual problem is (there is only so much you can get from an image). I can see that the multiselect is there but looks like it is in a disabled state so is that the problem?

Comment: @DavidShorthose i think its a ui issue. i am getting the results into it. but as you can see the structure of multiselect,thats an issue for me.

Comment: @DavidShorthose Does my approach for multiselect is right ? as i am trying in kendo for the first time..

Comment: The multiselect looks correct as in a textbox (although from your image it looks like there may be a height issue as the bottom looks cut off) which will then have either a single or multiple tags depending on your settings (in your case multiple) like this example here: https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/multiselect/index

Comment: @DavidShorthose Another issue which i have noticed is that i got the same data after selecting the item from dropdownlist.It is not clearing the previous data.is there a way to clear the previous seleected data?

Comment: You will need to do this on the change event of the dropdownlist or after you have refreshed the datasource for the multiselect by setting the multiselect's value to null or empty. This should point you in the right direction on the multiselect's api https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/multiselect/api

Comment: @DavidShorthose i have modified Code but the issue what i am getting is it is not clearing the previous Data. kindly check the link..   https://ibb.co/NFxshQ9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code worked for me:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        debugger;

        $("#DDRolecode").kendoMultiSelect({
            dataTextField: "Name",
            dataValueField: "ID",
        });

        ....
        ....

//go to controller and call Sp and get the result
success: function (result) {

                    debugger;

                    var multiSelect = $('#DDRolecode').data("kendoMultiSelect");
                    multiSelect.value([]);

                    $("#DDRolecode").data("kendoMultiSelect").setDataSource(new kendo.data.DataSource({ data: result }));                                    
                    var selectedData = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {


                        selectedData.push({
                            Text: result[i].Name,
                            Value: result[i].ID
                        })

                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the long comment chain.

From the second image you have provided it looks like the issue of `multiple` multiselects being added to the same item. This is due to you attaching a a new `multiselect control` to the same input.

this is a simple fix really. 
There are two ways to fix it. 
1) Destroy the kendo widget and recreate it 
2) Assuming the same structure is used in the underlying datasource and other settings just apply the new datasource data to the widget.

Here is a dojo showing you both examples:

https://dojo.telerik.com/UxetijUy/2

Personally I would go with option 2 as it is a `cleaner` solution and avoids having to constantly destroy and recreate widgets.

So if you change the required person in the second example it will take a random number of people from the data array for the multiselect and then rebind those options to that control.

So that is all you would have to do with your ajax call is once you have the result just apply the new data to the datasource and then you don't need to keep recreating the widget as you are currently doing.
So in your example:

```
       $("#DDRolecode").data('kendoMultiSelect').value(null);
       $("#DDRolecode").data('kendoMultiSelect').dataSource.data(selectedData);
```

This ensures you have cleared off any selected items before you have attached the new data source.

If you need more info on what is happening. Please ask and I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank u for the response..appreciated...:)