# How to take the selected text in Kendo multiselect variable?

Tags: javascript, ajax, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, kendo-multiselect

I have converted the kendo dropdownlist into kendo multiselect.

Dropdownlist contains 2 items:

1. D-UDMS-TMA Data Mgmt System
2. U-TDMS-SMA Mgmt System

```
$("#btnSendFlow").click(function () {

            debugger;

            var FlowData_array = [];

            //var ROLECODE = $("#DDRolecode").val().trim();---For dropdownlist output: "D"
            var ROLECODE = $("#DDRolecode").data("kendoMultiSelect").value();//added by chetan for multiselect output: "D" "U"

            // var MPID = $("#DDRolecode").data("kendoDropDownList").text().split('-');---for dropdownlist output: (3)["D","UDMS","TMA Data Mgmt System"]
            var MPID = $("#DDRolecode").data("kendoMultiSelect").value().split('-');//added for multiselect(How to do For multiple selected items?)-->
            output should be like:
            (3)["D","UDMS","TMA Data Mgmt System"]
            (3)["U","TDMS","SMA Mgmt System"]



        .....
        .....
        }
```

```
Commented lines is for Dropdownlist.
```

Output should be like for var MPID:

```
(3)["D","UDMS","TMA Data Mgmt System"]
(3)["U","TDMS","SMA Mgmt System"]
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `dataItems` method on the multiselect to get the underlying selected dataItems.

so all you should need to do is change your code from:

```
var MPID = $("#DDRolecode").data("kendoMultiSelect").value().split('-')
```

to:

```
var MPID = $("#DDRolecode").data("kendoMultiSelect").dataItems();
```

So this will give you an array of dataItems that you have selected. So if you need to only have the id then either change the `value mapping` to `valuePrimitive:true` or map the returning dataItems to the array list you need.

I have included a dojo showing how to get the items: https://dojo.telerik.com/ILEvITUQ

This is taken from the api demo dojo for multiselects but I have changed the `Get Values` button to map the items to their values only and also stringifying the dataItems array.

Answer (score 2):

You can do like:

```
var selectedValues = $("#DDRolecode").data("kendoMultiSelect").value().map(item => item.split("-"));
```

The result will be:

[image: Console result]

[Demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/iYurUDER)

Comment: var ROLECODE = $("#DDRolecode").data("kendoMultiSelect").value();
                 
           var MPID = $("#DDRolecode").data("kendoMultiSelect").value().map(item => item.split("-"));

Comment: @Dintvotedown.. i am getting the multiselect data from Sp. Kindly check the link.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57802489/how-to-convert-kendo-dropdownlist-into-kendo-multiselect?noredirect=1#comment102040518_57802489

Comment: @chetankambli your output is differente because your data is differente, i think.

Comment: i am not getting the result in your format..Thats exactly what i want ..i am just getting the value in a array like D and U

Comment: @chetankambli yeah I see that, but I'm saying based on img you added, that your data is not like you've posted in the question.. look at your data: https://i.stack.imgur.com/78GPn.png

Comment: i am trying to display the result for the variable MPID

Comment: @chetankambli you could simplify your code to `var MPID = control.dataItems().map(item => item.Name.split("-"));`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199248/discussion-between-chetan-kambli-and-dontvotemedown).

Answer (score 2):

The Below code worked for me:

```
var control = $("#DDRolecode").data("kendoMultiSelect");
            var selectedDataItems = control.dataItems();

            //// create an array that only contains the selected ids
            var MPID = [];
            $(selectedDataItems).each(function () {
                MPID.push(this.Name.split('-')); // you can access any property on your model here
            });
            console.log(MPID);
```